# Unable to use classes of one child module into another in multi-module maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, multi-module

I want to use the classes of one child module into another child module present in multi-module maven project. I have followed many existing solution. I am doing exactly same thing as in existing solution. But still it does not works.

Project structure:

```
Parent A: sampleproject
   |-- child A: Gui
   |-- child B: calculator
```

This is how  `pom.xml of parentA` looks like:

```
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>sampleproject</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
<modules>
  <module>Gui</module>
  <module>calculator</module>
</modules>
```

`pom.xml of child A` looks like:

```
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>sampleproject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>Gui</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

<dependencies>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>calculator</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
   </dependency>
<dependencies>
```

`pom.xml of child B` looks like:

```
<parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>sampleproject</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>calculator</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

When I perform `mvn install` on `parent` project. `jar` files are created in `calculator/target/name_of_jar.jar` and `Gui/target/name_of_jar.jar`. But when I check in `maven dependencies` of `Gui` project, only directory of `calculator` is created rather than `jar` file.

Here is image of `maven dependencies` in `Gui` project. 
[image: calculator jar file is not appearing in maven dependencies of <code>Gui</code> project]

Links I have followed: [use-a-class-from-the-other-child-module-in-maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46564146/use-a-class-from-the-other-child-module-in-maven) and [share-classes-within-modules-in-maven-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27406044/share-classes-within-modules-in-maven-project)

Comment: `"when I check in maven dependencies of Gui project"`: do you mean using the eclipse maven "dependency tree" view?

Comment: yes. tab that is created in project.

Comment: When it displays a directory icon, it typically means that the dependency is resolved in the workspace, which is expected as both projects are modules of the same project. **Is code failing to compile**?

Comment: no there is no any error. when i perform ```mvn install``` entire project and individuals modules are being performed smoothly.

Comment: Can you then please explain what the exact problem is?

Comment: @ErnestKiwale jar file of ```calculator``` is not properly appearing in ```dependencies``` of ```Gui``` project. I have added image in edited version of post. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: please see my previous comment about workspace dependency resolution. Eclipse displays that when the dependency is found in the same workspace. You can disable this in maven or project settings, then you'd need to build using mvn to see your dependency jar listed like others

Comment: @Ahmed Can you tell why you have dependencies to wagon, aether, plexus, plexus-classwords ? I have my doubts if this are really your dependencies you seemed to me doing something wrong...

Comment: Thanks very much @ErnestKiwele it worked.